# What effects of a magical strength increase that occurs during, and only during, the teenage years, have on human society and infrastructure?

Tags: society

What effects of a magical strength increase that occurs during, and only during, the teenage years, have on human society and infrastructure?

Like perhaps all strength is multiplied by 2, but all muscles and stuff act as if the teenager was only at normal, for us, strength.

But that's only to allow the strength increase to be used. Any secondary effects, like being hit by another teenager, would have results like the actual doubled strength.

Also, strength regulation is properly adjusted, again, via magic.

The teenage-years are defined as every year of age that, in English, has the suffix '-teen' in it, and strength arrives and leaves at midnight of the start, and end of the birthdays that mark the beginning and end of such years.

... That might be slightly, slightly useful for age identification?

Comment: This remembers me a lot of the series Charlotte

Answer (score 6):

Social questions like this are almost always "any result you want," because you can always adjust the culture to match your answer.

However, I would note that this is a very complicated time for a human being.  Lots of things are changing that they didn't think could ever change.  Highschool is horrible for some people because they just cannot cope with the changes around them.

You just made it a hundred times worse.

My assumption is that teenagers, given our current culture, would blow completely out of control.  Accordingly, I would expect the culture to shift to control them.

Given this, I would expect to see a culture form some right of passage that involves doing work for the good of society, with a strong focus on discipline.  The society is not going to want magical out of control teenagers running amok, so this would be drilled into them from birth.  You would be expected to do your -teen service, just as some nations have forced military service, then you will be allowed to rejoin society after your initiation ceremony.