# What would be a series of events such that modern adolescence isn't altered much if every human gained the ability to travel through shadows?

Tags: society, travel, transportation

**What would be a series of events such that modern adolescence isn't altered much if every human gained the ability to travel through shadows?**

The shadows have to be able to fit your body, and you have to have seen where you want to go.

The lighter the shadows, the harder it is to travel through. Having the darkest shadows on both sides makes it easy as stepping, or jumping or whatever, through.

The brightest shadows on both sides, means that it's barely traversable. You faint just from going through, and sleep for a whole day.

The spectrum of difficulty is set as the average of both shadows, so a super light shadow connected to a super dark one, means that you can barely stay awake.

Shining a light on shadows, makes them stop working as transportation, cutting things mid-traversal.

All the knowledge that's initially given to everyone in the world, by magic, is that people can go through shadows. The limitations have to be discovered. Newborn babies also have the shadow-travel knowledge.

You can only move something you're holding and wearing though. No draining water from the oceans with pipes that go into shadows.

Comment: I think you should look at some of the teleportation related questions and take your cues from there. Your question is very, very broad. We could write a short novel about the military implications for example. Another, probably _bigger_, novel could be written on parenting kids with teleporting toddlers. Might spell extinction for the human race just by having kids die from stupid mistakes. Anyway, my advice is to focus your question on a couple of key aspects.

Comment: @AndreiROM - Changed to a Adolescence focus...

Comment: How big do you believe the changes would be?  Do you believe this would have a small shift in adolescent culture, or do you believe this would completely up-heave all of known society, leaving a completely foreign society in its wake?

Comment: @CortAmmon - I have no idea. I'm hoping you guys can help me figure that out. Unless that's not the point of Worldbuilding...

Comment: I ask because there's a lot of ways to approach this question, some are outright degenerate.  The power of movement is an extraordinary power.  There's not only one way a world can go, and the larger the power you play with, the more ways it could go.  I could give you worlds where this power completely restructures society maybe 2 dozen different ways, but if you're looking for something that works its way into a book whose world is in any way remotely similar to our current one, those solutions won't be of much use to you.  Also, in many cases, the *way* we get given the power matters...

Comment: ... more than the power itself, so in many cases the possibilities are literally limitless.  Having a sense of what you expected to find in this world helps narrow down some of those limitless options.

Comment: @CortAmmon - Ah. It's like [this...](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/30115/6812) "Social questions like this are almost always "any result you want," because you can always adjust the culture to match your answer." ... I guess I'll ask about how to make the culture change as little as possible...

Comment: Interesting development on real teleportation: http://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-figured-out-what-we-need-to-achieve-secure-quantum-teleportation

Comment: This is mostly semantic anyway, as the shadow travel shown here is actually the ability to ravel through solid matter in places where other solid matter blocks light. Actual shadow travel, theoretically, would be the ability to move in the void between atoms and photons, with lower concentrations of particles (dark air) being easier to move through than higher concentrations (illuminated glass).

Answer (score 2):

[Not specifically about adolescence but about factors that could influence people in such a world.]

Nothing will be safe or secret anymore.
Rich and powerful people will have guards 24/7 to protect themselves and their valuables.

People will research luminescent materials and how to build things out of them (it can be a special pigment or bioluminescent lichen) so as to create impassable barriers.

Alternatively, mirrors and reflective materials could be used, as long as they're not easily broken. Floors could be made mostly of such materials so that you don't "phase through" involuntary. Everyone would wear pants.

Flickering lights could also be effective if they messed up with the shadow process enough, so rooms could have big central hearths or a central light with a mechanical contraption that generates moving shadows around it.

Conversely, spies and couriers will use networks of pitch black rooms, carry shadow-making devices (foldable screen + affixable bright light).

The technique of travelling through one's own shadow would be a dearly guarded secret.

"Light bombs" to disrupt the traversals of intruders.

A tactical and strategic advantage would be given to people who can control the weather, making artificial light more or less powerful outside by hiding or revealing the sun.

Comment: Cool! ... But I *just* focused on adolescence 'cause I'm sorta random right now... Changing to focus on security! NVM

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) You probably want an initiatic ritual then, at the end of which one can do one's first full body passage. Maybe because it requires some kind of physical transformation, like a mutilation or a tattoo.

Comment: Well, if you want to ask that, go ahead. But, I'm keeping my shadow-travel as something all humans can do.

Comment: no problem :) You'll just have to baby-proof houses with lights near all the walls and reflective floors then ;) Yeah, just realized that secure places could be made of mirrors too.

Comment: You gonna edit that in?

Comment: Done and I added a fashion tip ;)

Answer (score 2):

From our comment discussion, you'd like to keep the world similar enough to be recognizable.  The trick to doing this is to introduce the ability slowly.  If the ability is introduced slow enough, culture (and in this case, architecture) has time to shift to find the smallest changes needed to adapt to your change.

The first step I'd do is relax the knowledge of shadowwalking bit a little.  Unless your book has strong religious overtones, you'll find "knowledge from birth" to be a very rare thing indeed.  Many will argue that no such knowledge exists, but most will at least agree that there isn't much knowledge in that category.  Let's lighten it up so, instead, people simply don't have a particular tendency to believe you *can't* shadowwalk.  Thus, if you told me "I can walk through that shadow," I wouldn't immediately just presume you're telling the truth, but I wouldn't have the modern training to say "no way.  Nothing can walk through shadows."

Honestly, this isn't even all that hard to give.  Most young children believe almost anything is possible until they either hurt themselves trying or a truth worthy adult tells them it can't be done (and even then they do it, some of the time).

Next, we need something to slow the discovery down.  This ability needs to be discovered over time.  Why?  Consider "sneaking out at night."  It's an age old adolescent tradition.  It also gets really easy with shadowwalking.  This is going to tip the balance of power within the family towards the adolescent, and the family is going to need time to re-balance that.  It might involve floodlights, it might involve different locks or seals.  Whatever it involves, the parents are going to need enough time to figure out how to deal with this new ability, or adolescence will change shape dramatically.

One final addition I'd put into it is some risk or danger.  It's almost impossible to introduce a "free" skill without upsetting all sorts of balances.  So let's add some risk.  You mentioned potentially losing consciousness if you entered too weak of a shadow.  I'd like to take this a little further and ask the question "where do you pop out of the shadow?"  I'd like it to be highly volatile (I mentioned how many different answers there are to this!  This is just the one I'd run with if I was exploring worlds).  If you lose consciousness, you don't get to pop out of that shadow immediately, you pop out somewhere on the connected string of shadows you had entered (probably with a preference for following darker shadows).  Where?  Maybe people don't know.  Maybe scientists swear it is a random distribution, but some individuals have a hunch that your subconscious keeps trying to navigate your safely after you pass out.  Something flavorful.

Finally, let's make this a real skill.  At first, even entering inky black shadows should be hard.  You shouldn't presume it can't be done (you know better), but that doesn't mean its easy.  Your first shadowwalk may reliably result in you losing consciousnesses for a day, just because its hard.  However, you learn quickly how to navigate better.

With all of these changes, shadowwalking is not really any more of a daunting change than, say, puberty.  This is good, because families know how to deal with puberty -- we can deal with shadowwalking.  Parents will learn how to subtly gauge the shadowwalking skill of their adolescent children, to determine how much trouble they can get it.  Some children may be kept inside with nothing more than nightlights.  Others may require rope lights around every doorway to keep them indoors (rebel types).

School would be interesting because of parental and teacher responses to this ability.  Clearly adolescents will use it to hurt eachother with bullying.  Why? Because they do that with every single thing they have, so they'd do it with this too.  However, because the consequences for messing up are so great (a day of unconsciousness), the adults would step in, illuminating every bit of a school 24/7.

This, of course, is exactly the kind of acts which frustrate adolescents with their strict control, so I would expect lights to get mysteriously damaged.  The cool kids would hang out along paths where shadowwalking is possible.  The coolest would even prove how cool they are by traveling through thinner and thinner shadows.  You'd have dares to traverse a shadow line while the other kids flash the line with flashlights and laser pointers, trying to make you pass out.

Eventually, this would reach balance.  Architecture would lend a hand.  We'd eventually figure out how to structure schools so that the shadows are just easy enough to travel to be interesting, but not so easy that they are hard to follow.  You'd have skylights in places that are curiously hard to block.  The most useful shadows would go between places the adults wanted the kids to go in the first place, harnessing the rebellion.

The dangerous kids who roam the block in search of trouble would face another sort of story.  With such quick egress at night, they would have free reign to do a remarkable amount of damage.  People would quickly put up enough light to catch them approaching, but you wouldn't be wasteful and actually try to put up enough light to stop them.  Your job would be just to deter them, convince them to pick on another house.

Of course, there are the kind who don't accept these rebellious children.  There will be people who have floodlights and massive spot lights designed to catch them.  Some may even spend the money to get nice powerful moving lights which can show video.  When an alarm catches the kid in the act, these lights would create a doughnut of light around the perpetrator, trapping them in whatever shadow they end up hiding in.  They'd be held that way until the police arrive, though there may be a mysterious rash of teens "passing out for no apparent reason" while the police arrive -- the temptation to flash the last dollop of shadow the teen is trapped in would be very tempting.

I could keep rambling, but that's just one shard of one world which minimizes changes."  There's a lot of power in some of these approaches.

And are you sure you can't shadowwalk?  It's a lot easier to take the trash out if you know how...